Where can I view the list of successful sign-ins in my Microsoft Live account?
Where can I view the list of successful sign-ins in my Microsoft Live account? I don't see them on the recent activity page. I only see  unsuccessful sign-ins:


Successful sign-ins do appear in the recent activity page, but not immediately. It may take over 15  minutes to show up:

